# default date in multiple jquery datepickers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have several inputs that shares a class "date", each of them get it's value from DB and are converted to datepickers like this:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
});
```

What I need is that when I click any of the inputs and the datepicker is shown, the default date for that particular datepicker is the one stored in the value, not today's date.

How can I do that?

I tried the following without success

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    defaultDate: $(this).val()
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be over-thinking this. Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BQGEk/). Click each input and see the default date being the value of the input.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="date" value="02/05/2012" />
<input type="text" class="date" value="06/09/2015" />​
```

**JS**

```
$(function(){
    $(".date").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
    }); 
});​
```

Comment: You're right!! Turns out that the folks in charge of the css made no difference between a normal date and the default date so I always ended up seeing today as the only date with different color. Sorry!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
$(".date").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy"
}).on( "change", function() {
    $(".date").datepicker("option", "defaultDate", this.value);
});
```

This listens for when an input is changed and updates the `defaultDate` setting for all the datepicker fields. Note that you might need a different event (besides change) depending on how you're manipulating the inputs. Also, the current date value will always override the default date (so my code won't work with wanovak's example, because the fields already have values in them).